# Sigmoid Function

Tags: exponential-function

Typically sigmoid function is calculated as

```
    1/(1 + exp(-x))
```

I see sometimes it is calculated as

```
    1 - 1/(1 + exp(x))
```

or even

```
   exp(x)/(1 + exp(x))
```

Could you clarify the difference please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: They are all the same. Try some trivial operations to convert between formulas.

Comment: @Miguel thanks, when I use them in programming, I get minor differences in results. Could you suggest a tutorial that shows the conversion among different formats?

Comment: Multiply (1) by $\exp(x)$ and you get (3). Put common denominators in (2) and perform the subtraction, so you also get (3). Minor differences are probably due to limited computer precision.

Comment: @Miguel  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac
{1}{1+\exp(-x)}
=
\frac
{1}{1+e^{-x}}
=
\frac
{1}{1+e^{-x}}
\cdot
\frac
{e^x}{e^x}
=
\frac
{e^x}{e^x+1}
=
\frac
{e^x}{1+e^x}
=
\frac
{\exp(x)}{1+\exp{x}}
$$
and also
$$
1-\frac
{1}{1+\exp(x)}
=
1-\frac
{1}{1+e^{x}}
=
\frac{1+e^x}{1+e^x}
-
\frac{1}{1+e^x}
=
\frac{(1+e^x)-1}{1+e^x}
=
\frac
{e^x}{1+e^x}
=
\frac
{\exp(x)}{1+\exp{x}}
$$